# How to use a global variable declared in a header file inside a source file?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a cross platform C++ application for HP-UX and Linux.  I was wondering how I could go about using a const char * variable declared in file 1 inside file 3 without the following error popping up:

```
/usr/ccs/bin/ld: Duplicate symbol "OPERATING_SYSTEM" in files smac_dictionary.o and smac_dsl_parser.o
/usr/ccs/bin/ld: Found 1 duplicate symbol(s)
gmake: *** [smac_dsl_parser] Error 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Might be better to use macros and conditional compilation rather than runtime tests (this is the one real use of macros).

Comment: Did any of the answers provided answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

**[EDIT1]**

Saw reference to #define.  What he means is to, in your header file do this (myDeclare.h):

```
#ifndef __YOURNAMEHERE__
#define __YOURNAMEHERE__

// All of your declarations here
extern const char * myVar[6];

#endif
```

In myDeclare.c or cpp

```
const char * myVar[6] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
```

Now you should be able to include myDeclare.h anywhere, and the compile will only attempt to bring in your variables or code once.

**[ORIGINAL]**
I have always been able to do this by using the keyword extern on the declaration within a header file, then truly "defining" the variable within my c source file.

This should work even if you have to reference that same variable from multiple source files (i.e. header1.h being included into source1.c, source2.c, and source3.c).

This is also how you would do it in C++ (even though my example references .c files instead of cpp files)